# Not receiving cookies using axios post request to a local flask server

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios, session-cookies

Im trying to maintain an user session in flask using a webapp in React as the frontend.
I can send the post request and the flask server confirms that i logged in, but it does not maintain session, when i check the response header i do not receive the Set-Cookie.

Here is my flask code for login:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,supports_credentials=True,origins=['http://127.0.0.1:3000'])
app.secret_key = 'luladraoconquistoumeucoracao'

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

regex_email = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'


def create_login_return(error_message=None, user=None):
    resp = jsonify({"error_message": error_message, "user": user})
    # resp.set_cookie('same-site-cookie','foo',samesite=None)
    # resp.headers.add('Set-Cookie','cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None;Secure')
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    return resp

app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True,
    # SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None',
)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        '''SELECT admin,user_id,name,email,auth from user_data WHERE user_id = ? ''', (user_id,))
    user = c.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return User(*user[0])


@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    print(request.json)
    x = request.json
    print(current_user)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return create_login_return(error_message="Este usuário já está logado!")
    user, err = Users.get_user_for_login(x["user_id"], x["pwd"])
    if user is not None:
        login_user(user)
        return create_login_return(user=user.to_dict(), error_message=err)
    else:
        return create_login_return(err)
```

And here is the code that i am using for the React axios post request:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        const body = JSON.stringify({
            user_id: userID,
            pwd: userPwd
        })

       const res = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:6969/login",body,{
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
        console.log(res.data.error_message)
    }
```

Really need help on this one

Comment: Do you use https?

Comment: Not in this case, since it's running in local server.

Comment: Are you using http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/ on the front end or http://localhost:xxxxx/?

Comment: An insecure origin like `http://127.0.0.1:3000` simply isn't allowed to set a cookie with a `Secure` attribute.